# UITableViewController as subview swift

Tags: ios, swift, cell, subview, uitableview

I'm trying to make my first app and I'm stuck at this point.

My app looks like snapchat, a horizontal scrollview and the left part is composed of a tableview.
So, in this left part I put as a subview a tableViewController. The problem is the cells are always empty ! The table view is showing with the right cell's height but cells are empty.

I'm sure you can help me, thank you !

[I make the subview here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg7G4.png)

[Link with cells here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dXj5.png)

Comment: can you show ur tried  cocde

Comment: It is impossible to help you without seeing your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be ensure that override necessary methods in table view controller and balance calls in adding child view controller code rutin.One more last thing when adding child view controller you should provide correct size to controller view.

for adding table view controller as a child view controller

```swift
 guard let list = R.storyboard.dashboard.addressesController()else {
      return
    }

    self.list = list

    self.addChildViewController(list)
    self.scroll.addSubview(list.view)
    list.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    list.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

    list.view.snp_makeConstraints(closure: {
      (make) in
      make.left.equalTo(self.view).offset(10)
      make.right.equalTo(self.view).offset(-10)
      make.bottom.equalTo(self.scroll)
      make.height.equalTo(list.tableView.contentSize.height)
      make.top.equalTo(authorizedTop.snp_bottom).offset(10)
    })
```

for extending table view controller

```swift
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.cellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: You save me ! Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an answer to you question, but I have a suggestion which might help you in the long run, and maybe help you debug your current problem: 
How about splitting the tableViews' logic into separate `UITableViewController`s? That way you avoid some gigantic common `UIViewController`. You can use the *Container View* in your storyboard, which can embed a `UIViewController`.

[image: Container View in Storyboard]